# Is it possible to update an existing Windows Phone 8 app to Windows Phone Store 8.1

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-8, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1

I've a Windows Phone 8.0 app on the Windows Phone Store, and I want to update my app to Windows Phone store API (and not Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1) to prepare Windows 8.1 version.

Is it possible to update and migrate IsolatedStorage data from SL8 to Phone Store App?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**TL;DR;** - It preserves data on Isolated Storage when updating from WP8.0 to WP8.1 Runtime.

Because [the provided link to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/dn642081(v=vs.105).aspx) says only about Silverlight apps, and it's not clear (if I hadn't missed something) what would happen in case: I've old WP8.0 Silverlight App and now I decided to upgrade it to WP8.1 Runtime - I've performed a simple test:

1. I've published a Beta version of the App - WP8.0 Silverlight.
2. After successful instalation on the Phone, I've copied some files inside the App, so that there is something on Isolated Storage
3. I've submitted an update - went to Store, selected Beta version (WP8.0), clicked <kbd>Update</kbd> then <kbd>Upload and describe your packages</kbd>, after a while, <kbd>Add new</kbd> (**not** replace the old WP8.0 package), add some information, save and submit.
4. After some time my Phone is notified that there is an update for the App - I click <kbd>yeah - update</kbd>
5. After successfull instalation, I see that it's a new App, I click my special button to see what is on Isolated Storage and I see that there **are** old files from WP8.0 version

So it turns out that [LPains answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23788061/2681948) is correct (+1).

Comment: Thanks for testing. I relied mainly on the information in Upgrade a published Windows Phone 8 app section. It says that it is possible to upgrade with a APPX package which are exclusive to Windows Runtime apps (WP and Windows store apps). :)

Comment: Great news, isostore can be migrated.  Though what about IsolatedStorageSettings ?  I'm guessing this isn't, but would like to know for sure.

Comment: @Quincy ISS in WP8.0 was hold in xaml file in IsolatedStorage - you can view it. As I've checked LocalSettings (in WP8.1) are held somewhere else. As I've upgraded my app, there is a file `__ApplicationSettings` - hence I guess it's the same from WP8.0. It should be possible to deserialize it, thought it needs few tries with beta versions.

Comment: @JerryNixon-MSFT Whay you say that - have you obtained different results? That was the purpose of the test, and as I've double-checked now I've updated from WP8.0 (there was Silverlight only) to Runtime. Has something changed?

Answer (score 4):

Do you mean update the code or update the application in the store?

If you mean update the code, you have to recreate it from scratch. You may be able to use some content but a lot has changed on the new Windows Phone 8.1 (Windows Runtime) including how you write Xaml.

If you meant update in the store than yes, that will work. When you update your app with a new one on the new format the store automatically understands and migrates the IsolatedStorage data: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn642081(v=vs.105).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn642081%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Comment: the link provided is referring to SL8.1 therefore is not reliable.  Correct?

Comment: Not quite right. Have a look into the Upgrade a published Windows Phone 8 app section. It applies for both Silverlight and Store phone apps plus @Romasz tested it as well.