# Windows Phone 8 ApplicationSettings - Get settings in Universal app

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I'm upgrading windows phone 8 application. I created Universal app (Windows.Phone 8.1).

The settings in old WP8.0 application are saved in following way:

```
IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Add("MY_SETTINGS", value);
```

Question:
How can i get this settings when app is upgraded to WP8.1 (Universal app).

I try the following:

```
var localSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
var isContains1 = localSettings.Values.ContainsKey("MY_SETTINGS");
var roamingSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.RoamingSettings;
var isContains2 = roamingSettings.Values.ContainsKey("MY_SETTINGS");
```

But no "MY_SETTINGS" are found. (isContains1, isContains2 == false):\

Many Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

[LocalSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.localsettings.aspx) in WP8.1 works differently than those in WP8.0 - where settings were saved in a file (after serialization). The file is **__ApplicationSettings** - take a look at it (via IS explorer tool) and you will see its structure - part of it is a serialized dictionary. I've made [some research](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23792280/2681948) once, which showed that all the old files are preserved during the update - which means that the settings are still there.

Once you update your WP8.0 app to WP8.1 and you want to read your old settings, you can retrive the values from the file.

Comment: The __ApplicationSettings file is a dictionary serialized to the disk using [DataContractSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer(v=vs.110).aspx).

I haven't found a good way to rehydrate it back to the settings/objects for the general case, but a custom solution for a specific app works. You just have to play around a bit.

Comment: @Adam You are right. Thought I still hadn't deserilized settings, but after looking at its structure it seems that when you know what type you have saved it shouldn't be a hard thing to do for specific solution.

Answer (score 1):

[This blog post](https://www.pedrolamas.com/2014/08/14/upgrading-from-the-isolatedstoragesettings-to-applicationdata-localsettings/) has your exact answer, including the code needed to deserialize the migrated settings file!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ApplicationData.LocalSettings` It would Get you the application settings container in the local app data store. here is a [Dev center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.localsettings.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) link in which its Described how to use it.

Comment: Yes, but as you can see by the code snipper i don't get any values for "MY_SETTINGS"

Comment: have you implemented that ? first of all set values and after that try to get it. there is also a else part for your settings variable access into link