# How to migrate from IsolatedStorageSettings (WP8.0) to ApplicationData (WP8.1 runtime)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1

I have Windows Phone 8.0 app which uses IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings to store settings etc. Now Im planning to "update" this app to Windows Phone Store 8.1 app and use ApplicationData.Current.RoamingSettings.

How to migrate app settings, which are already saved to IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings to ApplicationData.Current.RoamingSettings?

Comment: you can still do something like `IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings` but this is the case for only the base types

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are updating to a Silverlight 8.1 app, `IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings` will still work. Just read the settings out and copy them to the `ApplicationData.Current.RoamingSettings`

If you are updating to a universal app the discussion is here: [Windows Phone 8 ApplicationSettings - Get settings in Universal app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25113478/windows-phone-8-applicationsettings-get-settings-in-universal-app/25114051?noredirect=1#comment39109191_25114051). The result is you are looking for the __Application Settings file and you'll want to deserialize it to get the settings out. There is no general solution, but if you know what you are expecting in the file, it isn't all that hard.

Comment: Thanks Adam! I was expecting something more straight forward but I think im able to pick needed information from the file.