# How can I test/debug the update process of my app from WP8 to WP8.1?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I am just about to release a big update to my app, which is currently WP8 only and I don't want users to lose their local app data.

1) Am I right that all the local data of the WP8 app is still available in the local folder afterwards?

2) Can I use the [update background task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn673541.aspx) to prepare the upgrade? Or does this only apply to WP8.1 → WP8.1 upgrades?

3) Is there any way besides providing the WP8 app as a Beta app and updating it to the WP8.1 version there? Can I test this locally on my device/in the emulator? I know there's some `/update` flag for the [application deployment tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn632395.aspx) but how does this work for WP8 → WP8.1?

I'd appreciate any help, maybe some of you have already done this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You may take a look [at procedure I've performed](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23792280/2681948), thought it's just what you have described at point 3. As for testing locally, I'm testing it like this: I install 8.0 app, copy files, modify etc. then I use Isolated storage explorer to copy all files from the app to computer, install 8.1 app, use ISE to copy files to new app. It should be the same as in Store - all files are preserved.

Comment: Oh dear, I hoped there would be a more elegant solution ;) Thanks for your helpful answer!

Answer (score 0):

1) Correct. User data persists through an update. User data is removed when the app is uninstalled.

2) This is a WP8.1 feature. You would need to have the background task registered before the upgrade. It isn't useful for the initial install.

3) Try with a test app, but I expect that would work fine WP8 to WP8.1

Comment: For 3) I unfortunately can't find a way to tell the deployment tool which app to update. I can install both the WP8 XAP and the WP8.1 APPX but how can I tell it to update the WP8 app with the new one? It seems to match product IDs, which are currently different.