# Update Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1(xap) to Windows Phone 8.1(appx)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

Suppose we have a Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1 app in the MS Phone Store, we port the app to use only Win(P)RT API resulting a Windows Phone 8.1 appx package containing the same identity (Name, Publisher, PhoneProductId, PhonePublisherId).

Is it possible to upload appx instead of xap for the same app on the store?
Will the installer be able to handle the update from xap to appx so that the local storage will be kept?

Comment: Isolated Storage is preserved during update - you can also take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23792280/2681948). Note only that Silverlight and RunTIme are two different APIs. I've tested it with WP8.0 -> WP8.1 Runtime, though I think should be the same with WP8.1 SL -> WP8.1 RT. The best would be if you could test it yourself with beta release.

Comment: Yes the documentation says that it should work and describes Silverlight 8.0 (xap) to 8.1 (appx) migration, which, as you mention is working. But when I tried to update (using MSVS2013) a Silverlight 8.1 (installed xap) to 8.1 (appx) with same identity fields, just an inc. version, it fails with "The app x is already installed on this machine. If you continue with the current deployment, the existing app will be uninstalled and the app's current state will be deleted. Are you sure you want to continue?". Now I setup a new test beta app into the real store and I'm in the middle of a test there.

Comment: It's probably the problem with VS deployment - the same situation will be if you had an app from store installed and try to deploy the one with same appid from VS. The beta test will give you the answer for sure.

Comment: MSVS deploy updates on WP80->WP81 and on WP80->WP81Silverlight->WP81 but re-installs on WP81Silverlight->WP81. The good news is that on MS Store deploy updates on all previous scenarios. Thanks Romasz.