# Creating update for WP 8 app to WP8.1 app

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

What I am trying to do is to publish update for my WP8 app. Locally I have retargeted it to Wp8.1 Silverlight. And then added it using dashboard as "Add new". So in my dashboard I have 8.0 version and 8.1 version right now with has higher version number. It is successfully published but when I receive an update it fails to install. I receive message that "Attention required. Tap here." in STORE app -> Downloads and I got this message:
"We're having troubles installing this app. If this is the first time you've seen this message, go ahead and try again. If the app still won't install, go to your Phone Update settings to make sure your phone software is up to date."

Also worth noting that locally I have installed my 8.0 based version. And then updated and deployed 8.1 version on top.

Does anybody has any clue where to look the origin of the issue?

Comment: How did you deploy the 8.0 version?

Comment: Localy using Debug -> Run. On the Dashboard -> I have created a Beta version of the application to test the update.

Comment: I could've sworn that I saw this asked over at http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/ where the answer was essentially, "The store can only update apps deployed from the store, and will fail if a debug version is present", can't find the exact link right now though

Comment: The main problem that I 99.99% sure that both versions were Release build

Comment: Have you checked if you are able to install WP8.1 version from the store without updating the old version? I've successfully [managed to do similar thing with Runtime version](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23792280/2681948).

Comment: The tricky thing here is that I tried several times and once it worked. Hard to describe why, but I do not remember what have I done :(

Comment: Ensure also that there is no the same app installed on yur phone via Visual Studio (only Windows Store's WP8.0 version), then update the beta in the store and wait if it will be possible to upgrade to 8.1.

Comment: Omg, there is a huge chance you were right. I just deleted the other version (which was installed from VS) and the version from the store installed. Need to test it more carefully tomorrow!

Comment: You won't install app from Store if there is an app with the same AppID installed by VS. And vice versa - if you have an app installed from Store and try to install any version from VS with the same AppID, VS should ask you if uninstall the version from the store.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be because you have an app with the same appId installed via Visual Studio (either debug or release version). The Store won't install the app in that case, it will promt about problems and so on.

The same situation is vice-versa - if you have an app installed form the Store and now you try to deploy it (the same appId - by default once you have created app packages, further builds will have the same appId as last created Store package), the VS will prompt that there is an app already on the phone and if you want to uninstall it.