# App update from 8.1 to 10

Tags: uwp, windows-10-universal

I have WinRT(Universal 8.1) app and it has been automatically available on Windows 10 and it works without problems.

The thing is I'm creating Universal App built specifically for Windows 10 so it can make use of all new features available out there.

Current (8.1) version stores data in the Local Folder (*ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder*).

The questions are

If I make new package for Windows 10 (it goes to the same App in Dev Center - just package is for W10), will all the data be persisted (answer is yes, but it's different package, so I dont't know for sure)?

Will the app be updated to the new version for W10 users or maybe it's considered as a different app and different catalog and everything will be gone?

Comment: I guess that the situation will be similar when [there was an update from 8.0 to 8.1RT](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23792280/2681948) - local data will be preserved. To ensure, the best would be to test it on beta app in the store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create the UWP app, associate it with the app you already have in the store as normal - right click on the project in Visual Studio, and choose Store\Associate App. Then, create your app package and upload it to the store as an update to your existing app. Your app will now have packages for both Win8 and UWP - but it is still just one app as far as the consumer is concerned.

Windows 10 users will automatically get upgraded to the UWP version, and all settings and local storage will be preserved. I have an app with both Win8 and UWP versions, and so can confirm that this is how it works.

Comment: Good to know without testing it through store. Thanks!