# Store update of 8.1 app to uwp app

Tags: windows-runtime, win-universal-app

I have a Windows Phone 8.1 app in the store. Now I have created an uwp update. My question is:
If I load an update of the app into the store and an user does this update. Is the app just overwritten or deinstalled and then new installed? And are the saved settings in ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings deleted?

thx newone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR;** - It preserves data in *LocalFolder* and *LocalSettings* when updating from *WP8.1 Runtime* to *UWP* (tested with mobile on device with *Insider preview - Fast ring*).

I've run similar test, [like the last time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23792280/2681948):

1. I've published a Beta version of the App - WP8.1 Runtime.
2. After successful installation on the Phone, I've created a file in *LocalFolder* and set value in *LocalSettings* (see code below),
3. I've submitted an update - went to Store, selected the App, clicked <kbd>Update</kbd> then <kbd>Packages</kbd>, after a while, <kbd>browse your files</kbd> and chosen the new generated appxbundle (I have **not** deleted the old WP8.1 package), save and submit.
4. After some time my Phone is notified that there is an update for the App - I click <kbd>update</kbd>
5. After successful installation, I see that it's a new App, I click my special button to check *LocalFolder* and value in *LocalSettings* - I see that there **are** old values from WP8.1 version.

Code for buttons used to test:

```cs
private async void Generate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    StorageFile file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("test.txt");
    await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(file, "Something inside");
}

private async void CheckFile_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        StorageFile file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("test.txt");
        string text = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file);
        await new MessageDialog($"File exists = {text}").ShowAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception) { await new MessageDialog("File desnt exists").ShowAsync(); }
}

private void GenerateSetting_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) => ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["CHECK"] = "Test value";

private async void CheckSetting_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values.ContainsKey("CHECK"))
        await new MessageDialog($"Setting exists = {ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["CHECK"]}").ShowAsync();
    else await new MessageDialog("Setting doesn't exist").ShowAsync();
}
```