# The number of ThisKey columns is different from the number of OtherKey columns

Tags: c#, linq, windows-phone-8, linq-to-sql

I am developing a Windows Phone App, and I am having troubles with the LINQ. When I try to run my application, it shows the message:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.Linq.dll
>
> Additional information: The number of ThisKey columns is different from the number of OtherKey columns for the association property 'Coletor' in the type 'Pessoa'.

I already tried everything that I found on google, but didn't worked. The files that are with problem is below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.Linq.Mapping;
using System.Data.Linq;

namespace Aplicativo_Windows_Phone
{
    #pragma warning disable 0169, 0649
    [Table(Name="Pessoas")]
    public class Pessoa
    {
        [Column(IsDbGenerated = true, IsPrimaryKey = true)]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Column]
        public string Nome { get; set; }

        [Column]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Column]
        public string Senha { get; set; }

        [Column]
        public string Profissao { get; set; }

        [Column]
        public int Idade { get; set; }

        [Column]
        public string Endereco { get; set; }

        [Column]
        public string Cidade { get; set; }

        [Column]
        public string Estado { get; set; }

        [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, Name = "Coletor")]
        private int? coletorId;

        private EntityRef<Coletor> _coletor = new EntityRef<Coletor>();

        [Association(Name = "FK_Pessoas_PessoaColetores", IsForeignKey = true, Storage = "_coletor", ThisKey = "coletorId")]
        public Coletor Coletor
        {
            get { return _coletor.Entity; }
            set { _coletor.Entity = value; }
        }

        private EntitySet<PessoaColetor> _pessoaColetores = new EntitySet<PessoaColetor>();

        [Association(Name = "FK_PessoaColetores_Pessoa", Storage = "_pessoaColetores", OtherKey = "pessoaId", ThisKey = "Id")]
        private ICollection<PessoaColetor> PessoaColetores
        {
            get { return _pessoaColetores; }
            set { _pessoaColetores.Assign(value); }
        }

        public ICollection<Coletor> Coletores
        {
            get { return (from pc in PessoaColetores select pc.Coletor).ToList(); }
        }


    }
}


using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.Linq.Mapping;
using System.Data.Linq;
using Microsoft.Phone.Data.Linq;
using Microsoft.Phone.Data.Linq.Mapping;

namespace Aplicativo_Windows_Phone
{
#pragma warning disable 0169, 0649
    [Table(Name="Coletores")]
    public class Coletor
    {
        [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true)]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Column]
        public float Latitude { get; set; }

        [Column]
        public float Longitude { get; set; }

        [Column]
        public string Nome { get; set; }

        private EntitySet<PessoaColetor> _pessoaColetores = new EntitySet<PessoaColetor>();
        [Association(Name = "FK_PessoaColetores_Coletor", Storage = "_pessoaColetores", ThisKey = "Id", OtherKey = "coletorId")]
        private ICollection<PessoaColetor> PessoaColetores
        {
            get { return _pessoaColetores; }
            set { _pessoaColetores.Assign(value); }
        }



        [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, Name = "Ocorrencias")]
        private int? ocorrenciaId;

        private EntityRef<Ocorrencia> _ocorrencia = new EntityRef<Ocorrencia>();

        [Association(Name = "FK_Coletores_ColetorOcorrencias", IsForeignKey = true, Storage = "_ocorrencia", ThisKey = "ocorrenciaId")]
        public Ocorrencia Ocorrencia
        {
            get { return _ocorrencia.Entity; }
            set { _ocorrencia.Entity = value; }
        }

        private EntitySet<ColetorOcorrencia> _coletorOcorrencias = new EntitySet<ColetorOcorrencia>();

        [Association(Name = "FK_ColetorOcorrencias_Coletor", Storage = "_coletorOcorrencias",ThisKey = "Id", OtherKey = "coletorId")]
        private ICollection<ColetorOcorrencia> ColetorOcorrencias
        {
            get { return _coletorOcorrencias; }
            set { _coletorOcorrencias.Assign(value); }
        }

        public ICollection<Pessoa> Pessoas
        {
            get { return (from pc in PessoaColetores select pc.Pessoa).ToList(); }
        }

        public ICollection<Ocorrencia> Ocorrencias
        {
            get { return (from co in ColetorOcorrencias select co.Ocorrencia).ToList(); }
        }
    }
}


using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.Linq.Mapping;
using System.Data.Linq;
using Microsoft.Phone.Data.Linq;
using Microsoft.Phone.Data.Linq.Mapping;

namespace Aplicativo_Windows_Phone
{
#pragma warning disable 0169, 0649
    [Table(Name = "PessoaColetores")]
    class PessoaColetor
    {
        [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, Name = "Coletor")]
        private int coletorId;
        private EntityRef<Coletor> _coletor = new EntityRef<Coletor>();
        [Association(Name = "FK_PessoaColetores_Coletores", IsForeignKey = true, Storage = "_coletor", ThisKey = "coletorId")]
        public Coletor Coletor
        {
            get { return _coletor.Entity; }
            set { _coletor.Entity = value; }
        }

        [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, Name = "Pessoa")]
        private int pessoaId;
        private EntityRef<Pessoa> _pessoa = new EntityRef<Pessoa>();
        [Association(Name = "FK_PessoaColetores_Pessoas", IsForeignKey = true, Storage = "_pessoa", ThisKey = "pessoaId")]
        public Pessoa Pessoa
        {
            get { return _pessoa.Entity; }
            set { _pessoa.Entity = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't have answer to your question but one suggestion. Don't use SQL CE. Eventually you will want to upgrade your app to universal apps in future and in that SQL CE is not supported. If you can, then use SQLite DB.
Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23726157/how-can-i-migrate-my-wp8-application-to-universal-when-it-uses-a-local-linq-to-s?lq=1

Comment: Have you tried explicitly setting your `OtherKey` property on the attribute? Just a guess, but try setting it to "pessoaId"?

Comment: @SvenGrosen I will read, thanks for the tip. About the key, I tried this and I still getting the same error, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

shouldn't this Primary key

```
[Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, Name = "Coletor")]
    private int? coletorId;
```

be foreign key

```
[Column(IsForeignKey= true, Name = "Coletor")]
    private int? coletorId;
```

Comment: This wasn't the problem. The problem was that the Coletor class needed to have a pessoaId to become the otherkey in the Pessoa class. Thanks anyway.